# Running a command on the remote host with interactive SSH (conditionally)

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, ssh

I would like to be able to automatically run a command on a remote host each time I log into that host, but within the current interactive SSH session.

Something like

```
ssh user@remotehost [run do.sh]
```

where `do.sh` does a couple of housekeeping tasks and then reattaches to a `screen` session (currently I run `do.sh` manually after logging into the host).

I don't want to add it to `.bashrc` because I login to this host from other machines and I don't want `do.sh` to run when I do login from there so I need it to be optional.

Comment: why you don't simply run `ssh user@remotehost /path/to/do.sh` ? If it works, you can even alias it in .ssh/config or your personnal .bashrc

Comment: So you want to run "do.sh" when you log in to remotehost from somewhere, but not when you log in to remotehost from somehwere else? Which hosts do you connect _from_ should trigger "do.sh", and which others shouldn't?

Comment: Yes, I want to run it sometimes, but not all the time, the reason for this is that I have a keyboard shortcut from a launcher on my Mac that gives me what I want _most_ of the time. I hit a shortcut and I want to ssh into the box and then reattach to a screen session, but I don't want to do that if I use a regular terminal like "ssh user@host". The solution mentioned below by Patkos does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
ssh server -t "do.sh; bash --login"
```

as suggested here: https://serverfault.com/questions/167416/change-directory-automatically-on-ssh-login

Or you could try using the 'LocalCommand' option in sshd_conf (or ~/.ssh/config) as described in the official man page: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1

Comment: Thanks so much!! ssh server -t "/home/user/do.sh; bash --login" worked for me. köszönöm szépen!

Comment: Szivesen (You are welcome)

Comment: @PatkosCsaba Please avoid other languages than English here. This applies also to comments.

Answer (score 3):

One part of the puzzle:  assuming OpenSSH, the `ssh` client will set the following environment variable:

> `SSH_CONNECTION`        Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: **client IP address**, client port number, server IP address, and server port number.

So you can use this information to find out *where your connection comes from*.